# forever scroll loading content dynamically with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, get, scroll

I have this code, and it works fine, problem is it keeps loading the content over and over again which yes I want but at the same time I don't. I want each time scroll to bottom a new page is loaded. Basically I am trying to create a Forever Scroll for my members list. The urls are the same except an integer which are split by 28s 0-28-56-84 so and so forth. 
  Code is

```
 function yHandler () {
   var wrap = document.getElementById('members_wrapper');
   var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
   var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
   var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
 if (y >= contentHeight) {
    $.get('/memberlist?mode=lastvisit&order=DESC&start=28&username',function(data) {
     var elems= $(data);
      $('#members_wrapper').append(elems.find('#members_wrapper'));
   },'html');

  }
}

window.onscroll = yHandler;
```

To be honest I am not quite sure how to go about this... I'm sure I could do the following,

```
var number = ["28","56","84"];
   for (var i = 0; i>number.length; i++) {
      var url = '/memberlist?mode=lastvisit&order=DESC&start='+ number[i] +'&username'
 }
```

Then in turn I could post in like so `$.get(url, function(data) {`

If this would work let me know, because the next issue would be, what if I have more than 84 members and one day go up to 200+ members? Would I then in turn do a mathematical equation, which I never have done so let me explain ...

if number has already passed + 28;

Yes I know that is incorrect since I don't know how to go about this per say. Basically what I need really is if the url has already been passed add 28 to it and then pass the next url once page scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.onscroll` handler will fire multiple times before the AJAX request has pulled in the content, which means you will fire multiple AJAX requests.

Keep track of when you are requesting the member list and don't run the onscroll handler if the AJAX request is still processing.

```
var fetchingContent = false; // tracks if an AJAX request is active

function yHandler () {
   var wrap = document.getElementById('members_wrapper');
   var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
   var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
   var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;

   if (y >= contentHeight && !fetchingContent) {
       // set to TRUE before AJAX request
       fetchingContent = true; 
       $.get('/memberlist?mode=lastvisit&order=DESC&start=28&username',function(data) {
           var elems= $(data);
           $('#members_wrapper').append(elems.find('#members_wrapper'));
           // set to FALSE after AJAX request complete
           fetchingContent = false; 
        },'html');
   }
}

window.onscroll = yHandler;
```

**EDIT**

To load the appropriate start value in the url you need to keep a reference to it.

```
var start = 0, limit = 28;

// once the AJAX request has finished you can update the start value
// notice the start variable is dynamically added to the AJAX url
$.get('/memberlist?mode=lastvisit&order=DESC&start='+start+'&username',function(data) {
    var elems= $(data);
    $('#members_wrapper').append(elems.find('#members_wrapper'));
    // set to FALSE after AJAX request complete
    fetchingContent = false; 
    // add to the start value for the next AJAX request
    start = start + limit;
},'html');
```

The problem with doing this client side is that you don't know when the total amount of users has been reached. So you need to check for a false response.

Server Side

```
$response = array();
if (no members found with given start value) {
    $response['success'] = 0;
} else {
    $html = {get members and build div}
    $response['success'] = 1;
    $response['html'] = $html;
}

// send JSON back to the client
echo json_encode($response);
```

Now you need to check for the success parameter in the AJAX response. Notice I changed the `$.get datatype` to `json`. You could also use `$.getJSON` instead.

```
$.get('/memberlist?mode=lastvisit&order=DESC&start='+start+'&username',function(response) {
    if (response.success === 1) {
        var elems= $(response.html);
        $('#members_wrapper').append(elems.find('#members_wrapper'));
        // set to FALSE after AJAX request complete
        fetchingContent = false; 
        // add to the start value for the next AJAX request
        start = start + limit;
    }
},'json');
```

Comment: How would I load different ajax request?

Comment: @EasyBB You mean with a different start value?

Comment: yeah the ajax request I would have is same url but different numbers. Page starts at 0 of course. then next is 28 then 56 so on and so forth increments of 28. I want if scrolled down on page 0 page 28 loads, then scroll down to bottom of 28 load 56 so on and so forth.

Comment: I can't do server side or this would be 100% easier ;) I don't have access to the php of the site. Give you an up vote that is for sure

Comment: @EasyBB thanks, well if you can't access the server then you must get some sort of null response if the start value is too high.

Comment: Yeah, so what does that mean? Sorry man just new to php coding so not very sure. Maybe I just won't do this I guess...